# Restrict VPN client on windows to ports or applications

Tags: windows-10, vpn, remote-desktop

My VPN provider is slow. I would like to use remote desktop (RDP, port 3389) over the VPN but look up other things locally, without the VPN connection, in my browser (e.g. chrome or Firefox). I run Windows.

I run some standard windows edition, how can I restrict my VPN connection? The client I'm using is 'Pulse Secure', but Juniper Networks through Windows VPN also works.

I found no good sources on restricting VPN clients to either applications or ports (either would work for me). What is an easy way to make this work?

Comment: If you use IPsec VPN (Juniper can do this), then you can use local Internet resources at the same time as you use RDP via VPN. I do this regularly

Comment: that's another client? Or is IPsec VPN natively installed in Windows? sorry, noob on this

Comment: IPSec is not native to Windows. You need an IPsec Client. In additions to the ones you mentioned, I use NCP Secure Entry (www.ncp-e.com)

Comment: ok, I don't see any options for local resources in Pulse secure VPN client, so I guess I'll try the NCP

Comment: Use a trial version and then work through the settings carefully.  Once the tunnel is connected, local resources are available.

Comment: You're referring to the NCP client?

Comment: Yes, the NCP Client Application. Shrew Soft makes an IPsec VPN client as well (https://www.shrew.net/download/vpn).  This is a free client but it has limitations (double NAT) that NCP does not have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99332/discussion-between-user2305193-and-john).